# R generating the difference of two column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create a new variable that is the difference of two other variables.

In particular, I tried to the following code:

```
> DF <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = rnorm(10), C = A - B)
```

But, the code does not work. So, how can I do that **without generating new object?**

p.s. I do not want to do the following one:

```
> a <- rnorm(10)
> b <- rnorm(10)
> DF <- data.frame(A = a, B = b, C = a - b)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution with `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

DF <- data.frame(A = rnorm(10), B = rnorm(10))

mutate(DF,C = A - B)
```